# ZSH Git aliases not working

Tags: git, zsh

I am trying to set this simple alias:

```
alias git plog = git log --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h%Cred%d%Creset - %C(cyan)%an %Creset: %s %Cgreen(%cr)'
```

In my .zshrc file. When I reload I get this:

```
no matches found: git log --pretty=format:%C(yellow)%h%Cred%d%Creset
```

If I put this in my .gitconfig

```
   [alias]
     ci = commit
     plog = log --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h%Cred%d%Creset - %C(cyan)%an %Creset: %s %Cgreen(%cr)'
```

Zsh shell gives me this each time:

```
$git:(embedded_gifs) git plog
zsh: correct 'plog' to 'log' [nyae]? n
```

Any ideas to fix this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the latter option of defining the alias in the `.gitconfig` file and either teach the auto-complete about the `plog` command or turn of auto-correction. Here is a brief [blog post](http://yountlabs.com/automation/disable-autocorrect-in-zsh/) explaining how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

The shell interprets 'git plog' by passing the 'plog' as the first parameter to the Git command, which it does not understand. If you make the alias one word, then it will work.

```
alias git-plog=...
```